# How to access data Using the php://input stream in Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, ajax, rest, codeigniter

I have a problem in my CI framework website. My AJAX (client) calls a ReSTful API (server) with PUT method.

In Server. I use :

```
putfp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$putdata = '';
while($data = fread($putfp, 1024))
  $putdata .= $data;
fclose($putfp);
parse_str($putdata, $output);
echo $output['name'];
```

And I had a value of `$name` from client. e.t.c for other variable. But in document guide of this Framework, they said like this:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-the-php-input-stream

My question is:

How to use `$this->input->raw_input_stream;`

Because I want to do like document guide said. I tried and result was all error. I don't know where I should put `$this->input->raw_input_stream;` into and how to get the data with that.

Anyone help me with example?

Comment: Remove junk, format the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `PHP` built in,
`file_get_contents('php://input')` method.

OR

Refer this URL
`https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#using-the-php-input-stream`

Hope this can help you.